# Maximal Inequality for a triangular array of negatively correlated (or even associated) random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, stochastic-calculus, expected-value

I am interested in maximal inequalities in the following setup:
Let $\left( (X_{n,i})_{i=1,\ldots, n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be random variables such that $X_{n,i}$ takes values in $\{0,\ldots, n\}$ for $i=1,\ldots, n$ and such that for all $n$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n X_{n,i}=n.$$
In particular assume that for all $n$ the family $(X_{n,i})_{i=1,\ldots, n}$ is negatively correlated (or even negatively associated) and that for all $a\in \{0,\ldots, n\}$ and $i=1,\ldots, n$
$$\mathbf P(X_{n,1} \geq a) \geq \mathbf P(X_{n,i}\geq a).$$

So it's easy to show (standard result I would say) for $s\geq 0$
$$ e^{ s \mathbf E[M_n]} \leq n \mathbb E\left[ e^{ s X_{n,1}} \right] .$$

But is there anything we can do to get a bound with $\mathbb E\left[{  X_{n,1}} \right]$ on the right side?

I would be glad for any hint, advice or literature...

Wish you all a nice day!